# Razor asp.net: access javascript variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I have this:

```
resources: [
    {
        field: "roomId",
        name: "Rooms",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { 
                    url: "@Html.Raw(
                        Url.Action(
                            "Filter_Rooms", 
                            "Room", 
                            new {
                                pFilter = false, 
                                pCapacity = 25, 
                                pBeamer = true, 
                                pTelevision = false
                            }))", 
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            }
        }
    }
]
```

These parameters  `pFilter = false, pCapacity = 25, pBeamer = true, pTelevision = false`, for the filter are now hard coded but actually I want them from:

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="chkBeamer" type="checkbox"> Beamer available
  </label>
</div>                              
<a href="#" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Filter rooms</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnFilter").click(function () {
        var pFilter = document.getElementById("chkBeamer").checked;        
    });
});
```

Can I get the javascript to use the `pFilter` parameter instead of the hard-coded ones?

---

**HTMLHidden**

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     @Html.Hidden("pBeamer", true);
     <input id="chkBeamer" type="checkbox"> Beamer available
   </label>
</div>
```

**Javascript Resources**

```
resources: [
    {
        field: "roomId",
        name: "Rooms",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { 
                    url: "@Html.Raw(
                        Url.Action(
                            "Filter_Rooms", 
                            "Room", 
                            new {
                                pBeamer = ("#pBeamer")???
                            }))", 
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `resources` that you are using is in Javascript, right ?

Comment: Yes in javascript indeed

Comment: Can you give the updated solution a try?

Comment: I still don't get it on how I can access that Html.Hidden then? I edited above...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can do this:-

1) You can have hidden fields for each of these four fields which you can fill in your Javascript function on click of `btnFilter`. Access those hidden fields while using `resources`.

```
@Html.Hidden("pFilter","<value>");
```

You can access these hidden fields in your code below.

```
resources: [
    {
        field: "roomId",
        name: "Rooms",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { 
                    url: "@Html.Raw(
                        Url.Action(
                            "Filter_Rooms", 
                            "Room", 
                            new {
                                pFilter = <get value from hidden field>, 
                                pCapacity = <get value from hidden field>, 
                                pBeamer = <get value from hidden field>, 
                                pTelevision = <get value from hidden field>
                            }))", 
                    dataType: "json"
                },
            }
        }
    }
]
```

2) You can have global variables to which you assign values on `btnFilter` click and use it in `resources` as you are doing currently.

I would suggest you to follow the first solution.

Comment: I can't use the document.getElementById... Name document does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user3629755: Can you give this a try? This should work.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it?

Comment: I still don't get it on how I can access that Html.Hidden then? I edited above...